# TokenAccountNotFoundError when trying to pass SPL tokens using anchor

Tags: anchor, spl-token, token, anchor-test, spl

I am trying to build an anchor project where I want to pass a specefic token from one address to another. The token was made using spl-token in cli.
I am getting TokenAccountNotFoundError when running anchor test.

Here is the anchor rust code:

```
pub fn transfer_tokens(ctx: Context<TransferTokens>, amount: u64) -> Result<()> {
    let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.from_token_account.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.to_token_account.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.authority.to_account_info(),
    };

    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);

    token::transfer(cpi_ctx, amount)?;

    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransferTokens<'info> {
    ///CHECK:
    #[account(mut)]
    pub from_token_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    ///CHECK:
    pub to_token_account: AccountInfo<'info>,
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
```

}

Here is the test code:

```
  const to = new anchor.web3.PublicKey("EtaPZdsxmKUrumNr6EgUoVaguqdeGHGKAVqnrGtFjeup");

  let bs = bs58.decode("<PRIVATE_KEY>");

  const from_keypair = anchor.web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(bs);

  const tokenAddress = new anchor.web3.PublicKey("8UWrbejwzaaYGSeNjzAaLZMv6vitTwf7fZ9bxC2wU5Vr"); // ADDRESS OF THE TOKEN I WANT TO PASS


const payer = await getKeypairFromFile("~/.config/solana/id.json");
const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

const from_ata = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  from_keypair,
  tokenAddress,
  from
);

const to_ata = await getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount(
  connection,
  payer,
  tokenAddress,
  to
);

const tx = await program.methods
  .transferTokens(new anchor.BN(10))
  .accounts({
    fromTokenAccount: from_ata.address,
    toTokenAccount: to_ata.address,
    authority: payer.publicKey,
    tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  })
  .signers([payer])
  .rpc();

console.log(tx);
```

Comment: What's the `tokenAccount` in getOrCreateAssociatedTokenAccount function?
It was supposed to `tokenAddress`, right?

Comment: Token account was the derived account, the one you get after runnig "spl-token create account" in the cli. I had also tried with tokenAdress, but it is not working as well